# How to display one innerHTML before another innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display one innerHTML element before another one is called in a function, currently my second innerHTML is showing by default. So the one that is in the function buySquare(); is shown. Is there a way to stop this happening and have the first innerHTML displayed and then the second?

```
/**
 * Moves players pieces around the board. 
 */
function movePiece() {
    let diceRoll = rollDice();
    if (currentPlayer === players[0]) {
        currentPosition1 += diceRoll;
        if (currentPosition1 >= board.length) {
            currentPosition1 -= board.length;
        }
        let currentSquare = squares[currentPosition1];
        currentSquare.appendChild(pieceOne);
        message.innerHTML = `${players[0]} you are on ${pieceOne.parentElement.getAttribute('data-type')} `;
        if (squareOwned === false) {
            buySquare(currentPlayer);
        }
        currentPlayer = players[1];
    } else {
        currentPosition2 += diceRoll;
        if (currentPosition2 >= board.length) {
            currentPosition2 -= board.length;
        }
        let currentSquare = squares[currentPosition2];
        currentSquare.appendChild(pieceTwo);
        currentPlayer = players[0];
        message.innerHTML = `${players[1]} you are on ${pieceTwo.parentElement.getAttribute('data-type')}`;
    }
}

var squareOwned = false;
async function buySquare(currentPlayer) {
    if (currentPlayer === players[0]) {
        message.innerHTML = `<p>Would you like to buy ${pieceOne.parentElement.getAttribute('data-type')}`;
        let input = await getUserInput();
        if (input === 'y') {
            console.log('you have bought this square');
        } else {
            console.log('you have not bought this square');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Display one string, then use `setTimeout()` to display the second string later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there is a way, what we need is a litte sleep (pause).

Add the top of your code add:

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res,ms));
```

What is this doing? It creates a promise that will be *resolved* after a number of milliseconds. Since **await** is just a nice way of waiting for a *promise* to be resolved we can now sleep/pause the code inside async functions.

Now you have a sleep/pause function that works inside all async functions: **await sleep(milliseconds)**.

Then before each **innerHTML** update to the DOM, sleep as long as you want:

```
await sleep(2000);
```

Change your function declaration **function movePiece** to **async function movePiece** to take advantage of this.